# Generate DWG file in runtime java

Tags: java, pdf, type-conversion, autocad

I want to generate a dwg file in runtime using java. Is it possible? I tried searching it on internet for hours but it only allows to read an existing dwg file and not to create one from scratch in runtime.

The main goal of this is I want to convert a pdf to dwg file to be opened in Autocad. I am aware that this feature is now available in latest versions of autocad but I want to create it myself.

But since I haven't found any direct convertion from PDF to DWG

What I am trying for now is

- read a pdf document
- create an empty dwg file
- transfer all the contents of the PDF to the empty dwg file.
- save dwg file.

Comment: What about DXF? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639855/generating-autocad-files-with-java

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question, like less than a day ago? [Converting PDF to AUTOCAD DWG FILE - JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62942979/converting-pdf-to-autocad-dwg-file-java)

Comment: Yes @Uroš .but it does ask for a direct convertion from PDF to DWG file which is not possible in java and did not get any answer.